# Forcing urls to rewrite/redirect?

Tags: php, .htaccess

This rewrite methode works, but its not Forcing urls to rewrite/redirect to the new urls.

I use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)$ search.php?q=$1
```

i can access rewrited urls (project/page/etc..) , but old urls/links (search.php?q=etc) still accessible without redirect.

note: i use `$_SERVER` variants to creating urls, and on localhost.

Comment: Is this really a problem? What about search forms that may point to `search.php`?

Comment: making dublicated pages is big problem for us..

Answer (score 4):

You have to **rewrite** project/page to search.php? in order to hide the ugly urls.

And **redirect** search.php? to project/page in order to make the canonical urls the only way to access that resource.

In your code there is no mention of the redirect, you're just rewriting.

Think of it this way

- rewrite hides the ugly urls behind canonical urls (it hides them, it doesn't eliminate them);
- redirect responds to the browser with a message like "search.php? has moved to project/page, try that link instead" and the browser follows the new link;

Comment: search.php dosnt really a "user search" prosess.. its only getting refferal queries and searchs them in database.  
but thanks for notes.

Comment: As an SEO rule, you should't have the same content accessible via more than one url. That's why you do the redirect from www.example.com to example.com, and the same is valid here.

Answer (score 1):

To redirect so called `ugly URLs` to SEO friendly URL you would need another Rewrite rule. Have your .htaccess code like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+) search.php?q=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+search\.php\?q=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ page/%1? [R=302,L]
```

Once you have verified that it's working fine change `R=302` to `R=301`.

Answer (score -2):

You'd need a `[R=301]` on the rewrite rule to turn it into a client-side redirect. Otherwise it's purely an internal rewrite and the client will never see the url getting changed.

e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)$ search.php?q=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: a question: i need to tell php to make "/page" urls insteade of using automated $_SERVER variants?  we dont want long urls to be created.

Comment: yeah, php won't know anything about the rewrites taking place, other than having the original un-rewritten url in a $_SERVER variable somewhere (can't remember the name offhand). php will have generate the clean urls in anything being sent to the client, otherwise the client will see the ugly query var versions.

Comment: $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is the original request I think